# Why does my database crash when I leave the page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce

Whenever I navigate to a particular page and then leave it some tables are deleted.  The only thing that differs between this page and the rest is that this page uses a different `DbContext`.  The tables deleted are also part of a different `DbContext` which is not used on the page visited.  This has really got me, any suggestions?

The controller that crashes the page is.

```
public class GenerationController : Controller
{
    private GenerationDbContext GenerationDb = new GenerationDbContext();
    private string generatedDir = "~/App_Data/Generated";

    //
    // GET: /Generation/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new GenerationIndexViewModel
        {
            Generations = GenerationDb.Generations
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.GeneratedOn)
                .ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        GenerationDb.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I just realized I have another page that accesses both `DbContext`s.  For some reason, I can navigate to this page and then leave without deleting tables.  It is just this one page that deletes all the tables for the other context.

**UPDATE:**  When I change the `Index` action to.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("Hello.");
}
```

I can navigate between the page and all the other pages fine.  No errors about tables being deleted.  Ergo, I'm positive it has to do something with the model or database context.  Which are so.

```
public class Generation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime GeneratedOn { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(4000)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GenerationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Generation> Generations { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  Using the Database Explorer provided with VWD, there is the `Generations` table when I navigate to the page.  And when I navigate to another page that use a different database context, the `Generations` table is still the only table.  Argh!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this is happening on the page one lands on after leaving _this_ page?

Comment: Yes.  When ever I navigate between the other pages it works fine.  It only crashes after I navigate to this page and then to one of the other pages.

Comment: All the tables belonging to a different `DbContext` are deleted.  Which crashes the website because the tables the page wants aren't there.

Comment: Let me clarify my comment: I am asking if you are using EF Code First. It occurs to me my comment looked like a standard "we need to see code" comment! Hehe

Comment: I'm not really sure what Code First is, but I am using EF.

Comment: Well, I ask because Code First contexts will do what you seem to have happening here, if you have two separate contexts set up to point to the same database. How did you create your database and the EF model classes?

Comment: You are right.  There are two contexts set up to point at the same database.  I coded the contexts and models from scratch.

Comment: Sounds like Code First is your issue then. You either need to moce each context to its own databse, or combine the contexts. There are other options, but these are the simpliest to uickly do and verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have Code First; the first time each dbcontext runs, it checks the database it is configured to connect to. If the schema is not what it expects to find, it flattens the database and recreates tables based on the model classes used by that context.

There are numerous paths to solve this. The easiest are to combine your contexts, or direct each one to its own separate database.